# How do I use an Django Rest Framework with API key per account (not user)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

For Django, both tastypie and django-rest-framework seem to be focused on API authentication/authorization/throttling per user. I want to expose an API that is per account, where an account might have multiple users administrating it. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django-rest-framework can achieve this. You don't have to throttling a user, these are options. You could have **Basic Authentication** for one account (username and password) that multiple user have access to.

You have **Custom Authentication** will any manner of options. Digest Authentication and much more.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to achieve this by copy-pasting the stock authtoken.Token model class and changing the user field to reference my Account model, and creating a custom Authentication class which simply inherits from the stock TokenAuthentication class and changes the model property to this Token class. Note that I could not inherit from Token simply to change the user, because Django does not allow field overrides in inherited model classes. It would be nice if the framework would find a way to work around this.